# Concat element in a loop with Separator

Tags: xml, xslt

The problem I'm facing seems simple. What I want to do is build a string by concatenating the results of a foreach element loop.

Data XML:

```
<OutboundPaymentInstruction>
<DocumentPayable>
            <DocumentNumber>
                <ApplicationInternalID>200</ApplicationInternalID>
                <ReferenceNumber>TEST_003</ReferenceNumber>
                <DocCategory>STD INV</DocCategory>
                <SequenceName>SEQ1</SequenceName>
                <SequenceValue>520822000792</SequenceValue>
            </DocumentNumber>
</DocumentPayable>          
<DocumentPayable>
            <DocumentNumber>
                <ApplicationInternalID>200</ApplicationInternalID>
                <ReferenceNumber>TEST_004</ReferenceNumber>
                <DocCategory>STD INV</DocCategory>
                <SequenceName>SEQ1</SequenceName>
                <SequenceValue>520822000792</SequenceValue>
            </DocumentNumber>
</DocumentPayable>
<DocumentPayable>
            <DocumentNumber>
                <ApplicationInternalID>200</ApplicationInternalID>
                <ReferenceNumber>TEST_005</ReferenceNumber>
                <DocCategory>STD INV</DocCategory>
                <SequenceName>SEQ1</SequenceName>
                <SequenceValue>520822000792</SequenceValue>
            </DocumentNumber>
</DocumentPayable>
</OutboundPaymentInstruction>
```

Expected output: `TEST_003/TEST_004/TEST_005` and should not cross 140 characters.

I tried with XSL file but ReferenceNumber is coming as like in the Image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8iPE.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="OutboundPaymentInstruction">
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <xsl:variable name="Invoices" select="DocumentNumber/ReferenceNumber"/>
            <Ustrd>
                <xsl:for-each select="DocumentPayable/DocumentNumber">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
            /<xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Ustrd>
        </Document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: I have provided all as you mentioned. Can you look it again.

Comment: ##3,4 are still missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the contents of your for-each loop, and omit the implicit whitespace:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="DocumentPayable/DocumentNumber">
                <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How can I restrict the outcome to 140 characters?

Comment: Thanks, This worked but how can we restrict output to 140 characters?

Answer (score 0):

One single function call will do the job without any loop.

**XSLT 2.0 fragment**

```
string-join(/OutboundPaymentInstruction/DocumentPayable/DocumentNumber/ReferenceNumber, "/")
```

**Output**

```
TEST_003/TEST_004/TEST_005
```

Comment: `string-join()` requires XSLT 2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT ignores text nodes in the stylesheet that consist entirely of whitespace, but it doesn't ignore whitespace that's adjacent to visible text. So in your example, the whitespace that precedes the "/" separator is considered significant. You can get around this by using `<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>`, or by including it in the value-of instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('/', ReferenceNumber)"/>
```

Comment: How can I restrict the outcome to 140 characters?

Comment: It's best to ask one question at a time, and it's best to tell us which XSLT version you are using.

Comment: I have asked all at once you guys not reading it fully.. I have mentioned it expected output

Comment: Several people have asked you which version of XSLT you are using, and you haven't responded. I'm not going to waste my time and yours giving you an answer that might not work with your version of XSLT.

Comment: It’s already mentioned in sample XSL , version is 1.0….

Comment: The fact that your stylesheet says version="1.0" doesn't mean you are limited to a 1.0 processor. But if you want a 1.0 solution, I'm afraid you'll have to get it from someone else - it's over 20 years since I last used XSLT 1.0.